# Ember JS : Exlude running eslint on js files of addon

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, eslint, ember-addon

I am using eslint ("ember-cli-eslint") for my ember application. Whenever i run the tests, eslint includes files from addon's as well(check screenshot). We have 5 custom add-ons which is used in this project. Eslint currently includes the files from these add-ons. Need guidance on how to exclude files from eslint.

[image]

I have also created ".eslintignore" file and added below line, but its of not use

```
modules/**/*.js
```

Comment: Do your addons have `isDevelopingAddon` in their `index.js`? If so, add `hintingEnabled: function() { return false; }` to their `index.js`.

Comment: Thanks, This worked. Can you add this as answer, will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An addon's `hintings` are run when `isDevelopingAddon` function of addon returns true. To disable it, you should give `hintingEnabled: function() { return false; }` in `index.js`.

Releated issue: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5594

--

**Edit**

Returning `false` from `hintingEnabled` also disables linter to run in that add-on. So if you want to enable linter in add-on and disable it while using in another app use the following check:

`return this.moduleName() === this.app.project.name()`